# How can I open urls in separate browser windows using python’s web browser module?

Tags: python, window, python-webbrowser

I’ve been trying to open multiple (30+) links but for website-specific reasons, after a certain amount of tabs have been opened, the open tabs start to crash. To fix this, I want to open some of my tabs in one browser window and the rest in a completely separate one. I want to accomplish this by using the webbrowser module and only the webbrowser module (for personal reasons). A possible solution is to use one browser (eg Firefox) for some of the tabs and then switch to another one (eg Chrome) for the rest but I don’t know how to do that...

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time

def open_websites(url, tabs, delay):
    tabs_opened = 0
    while tabs_opened < tabs:
        webbrowser.get().open_new_tab(url)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x=1267, y=572) #move mouse to button's coordinates
        time.sleep(delay)
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "d", interval=0.05) #to click a button using shorcuts
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "e", interval=0.05) #also to click a button using shorcuts
        time.sleep(3)
        pyautogui.click() #to click the button at the specied coordinates
        tabs_opened += 1
        if tabs_opened == 3:
            while tabs_opened < tabs:
                webbrowser.get(using="mozilla").open_new_tab(url)
                pyautogui.moveTo(x=1267, y=572)
                time.sleep(delay)
                pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "d", interval=0.05)
                pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "e", interval=0.05)
                time.sleep(3)
                pyautogui.click()
                tabs_opened += 1


open_websites("https://meet.google.com/ymj-cifg-fts", 6, 3)
```

Documentation of the webbrowser module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: Would you like to post some code so we can help you? What have you tried?

Comment: I get the following error code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "directory", line 30, in <module>
    open_websites("https://meet.google.com/ymj-cifg-fts", 6, 3)
  File "directory", line 20, in open_websites
    webbrowser.get(using="mozilla").open_new_tab(url)
  File "directory", line 65, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser